# Submit data of form with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit the data for this form, which has 3 different buttons:

```
<form action="/game.php?village=8404&amp;screen=market&amp;mode=own_offer&amp;action=modify_offers&amp;h=85fd1491" method="post">
  <input class="btn btn-cancel" type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete">
  <input type="text" size="2" name="mod_count" value="1" onkeydown="return no_enter(event)">
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Increase" name="increase">
  <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Reduce" name="decrease">
</form>
```

I would like to either submit the data in the same manner of "increase" or click that submit button. Ideally, I wouldn't have to replicate the URL which appears after the `form action=` as this varies from page to page.

When the form has a definite id, I've been using:

```
$('#thisFormId input[type=submit]').click();
```

But can't work out.

So how I can do that in this instance?

Comment: Could you slightly modify your game.php file? If so, you could send a post attribute, _action_ (for example) that would tell if increase or reduce was clicked. You can assign the value of _action_ depending where your user clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the questions:

`$("input[name=increase]").click();`

will trigger the click event of the Increase button and submit the form, which is what you want?

Comment: Yes... I swear I tried that. Feel a bit silly now. That works perfectly, thankyou. I will accept as answer as soon as i am able.